# Amazon SES Inline Attachment in .NET

Tags: .net, amazon-ses

We have been successfully sending emails through Amazon SES raw email format for a few months, and we have attachments working great.  However, we recently attempted adding an inline attachment (a simple jpg) so the user wouldn't have to open the attachment to verify the image and data correlated.

I'm using System.Net.Mail.MailMessage which is sent to a MemoryStream, and passed on to Amazon SES.  When I try to use a standard System.Net.Mail.Attachment and specify it with a content-id and content-disposition "inline", it sends the email and attaches the image but it doesn't put the image inline.

So we tried the LinkedResource (the correct way to do inline images in .NET), and SES throws an error of "Illegal Content Disposition".

Has anyone been able to send an inline image via Amazon SES?  Preferably in .NET, but any language is an option at this point if .NET cannot do it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but are you aware that you can now use [standard .NET mail API in conjunction with AWS SES](http://tekaris.com/blog/2012/07/25/sending-email-through-aws-ses/)? This could solve your problem.